# How best to model a company and it's address in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have a "company" resource. When the user signs up for a free account they only have to enter an email address. When they wish to upgrade their account, i need to take additional details from them such as their address. How best to model this?

1. Store the address details in the company table?
2. Have a separate "address" table with one to one mapping with companies, and upgrade
   would be on the address new action?
3. Create an action on the company resource that upgrades account, and takes the address info?
4. Create a new resource called "upgrade" which adds the additional address info
   into the company table?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

"premium" should be separated from "being/representing a company". I'd go with a separate `Company` model, with enough fields for address etc.

A `Company` will then belong to `:user`, and a `User` will have one `:company`.

See the `adr` microformat (http://microformats.org/wiki/adr) if you need hints on which fields to use for addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I could see you having a separate model for Address or just storing it on Company.  Personally I would probably choose having a separate model because in any given system it's likely you'll have Addresses associated with multiple models.  Another benefit is that it helps separate out address-related responsibilities from Company.

I would set up your validations like this:

```
Class Company
  has_one :address
  validates_presence_of :address, :if => :upgraded?
  validates_presence_of :email
  ...
  private

  def upgraded?
    <true if user has upgraded, else false>
  end
end
```

Comment: What model would you have the upgrade action on? could it be done restfully?

Comment: I would have the upgrade action on the Company.  You could do this restfully via a field that identifies if the company has been upgraded (i.e. a boolean called 'upgraded' or a string called 'state').  Is the interface the users are interacting with a website or a web api or something else?